# Permutation Hypothesis Testing procedure

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, bootstrap, permutation-test

I'm not strong in statistics and I'm looking for a help. I work with real estate data and I want to compare apartment prices in 2 districts: **district "A"** and **district "B"**.

Data description:

**array "A"**:

$mean_A$ = 368.52

$std_A$ = 256.02

$n_A$ = 2040

**array "B"**:

$mean_B$ = 340.02

$std_B$ = 284.02

$n_B$ = 2741

Looking at the data, it seems that district A is more expensive than district B. I want to be sure about it and make an experiment.

The observed statistic : $mean_A - mean_B$ = 28.5

$H_0$: $mean_A - mean_B$ = 0

$H_a$: $mean_A - mean_B$ > 0

That I did:

1. I shifted array A by 28.5(observed statistic) to center $mean_A - mean_B$ right on 0.
2. I simulated 10000 random samples for array A and for array B (sampling with replacement), get 10000 mean-differences and save them.
3. Next I want to see there the original observation(28.5) is on that distribution mean differences and calculate p-value.

*p-value* = (the number of values that are >= 28.5 ) / 10000

and is equal to 0.001.

So the difference is significant and I can reject $H_0$.

Tell me please, is it ok this procedure or I'commited mistake.

I would appreciate any piece of advice. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing seems more like a bootstrap procedure than a permutation
test. Because I don't have your data or a description of it, I can't be
sure why you aren't using a Welch 2-sample t test or a 2-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test.

Suppose I have data as below, as sampled in R. Even though sample sizes
are very large, I would not want to trust a t test with such severely
skewed data.

```
summary(a);  length(a);  sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  112.2   188.8   285.1   368.7   463.2  1904.2 
[1] 2040
[1] 254.4081
summary(b);  length(b);  sd(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  56.03  141.93  256.71  347.55  461.82 2611.67 
[1] 2741
[1] 292.5565
x = c(a,b);  gp = rep(1:2, c(2040,2741))
boxplot(x ~ gp, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

I will not use a t test because I do not trust the t statistic to
have t distribution. However, I will use the pooled 2-sample t test
statistic as my 'metric' for a permutation test, because I feel
the t statistic is a reasonable way to express the difference between
values in groups A and B.

```
t.obs = t.test(x ~ g, var.eq=T)$stat;  t.obs
       t 
2.613055
```

Now I will use `sample(gp)` to randomly permute the `1`s and `2`s in `gp`. All $2040 + 2741$ are reassigned to groups 1 and 2 with $n_1 = 2040$ in group 1 and the rest in group 2. On a much smaller scale the code
below illustrates one permutation of the vector `c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)`.

```
sample(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
[1] 2 2 2 1 1 2 1
```

I will do $10\,000$ permutations of `gp`,
finding `t.prm` for each permutation. Then the P-value of the permutation test will be the proportion of the values in `t.prm` that are larger
in absolute value than `t.obs` for the original unpermuted data.

```
set.seed(2020)
t.prm = replicate(10^4, t.test(x~sample(gp),var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) > abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.0079
```

The P-value is about $0.008$ so we reject the null hypothesis that the
two groups have the same mean.

[image]

```
hist(t.prm, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Simulated Permutation Dist'n")
  abline(v = c(-t.obs, t.obs), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

*Notes:* (1) A Wilcoxon rank sum test shows that the two groups
have significantly different locations:

```
wilcox.test(x ~ gp)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x by gp
W = 3138800, p-value = 3.737e-13
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

(2) For a one-sided test, as in your question, the last line of R code for the P-value would be as follows:

```
mean(t.prm > t.obs)
[1] 0.0042
```

(3) I am not familiar with the test you did. It seems to be a bootstrap test (because of re-sampling with replacement). I'm not saying your test is wrong; it gives a reasonable result. However, you asked about a *permutation test;* your test is not a permutation test; so I showed you one.

(4) The R code below was used to obtain the two samples used in
the discussion above:

```
set.seed(2020)
a = rexp(2040, 1/256) + 112
b = rexp(2741, 1/284) + 56
x = c(a,b);  gp = rep(1:2, c(2040,2741)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, as I said I'm not strong in Statistics. I'm not familiar with Welch o Wilcohox test, neither familiar with R(only Python). I'm going to read about this two tests and read about the difference between bootstrap test and permutation test.

Comment: If you have specific questions about the R code, please ask. I will try to explain the most mysterious parts. At the end: `t.perm` is a vector of $m=10\,000$ t statistics from permuted tests; `abs(t.prm) > abs(t.obs)` is a logical vector of $m$ `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s and its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s. // The Welch t test requires nearly normal data, but does not require that the two group variances be equal. The Wilcoxon rank sum test does not require normal data, but works most transparently if the two samples are from populations of about the same shape.

Comment: Thank you, very much for your help. You were right this is Bootstrap procedure I was reading some papers and I found an error in my procedure:
3. Next I want to see there the original observation(28.5) is on that distribution mean differences and calculate p-value. <= here I made a mistake.

The right way to shift my data is:

array(A) = array(A) - mean(A) + mean(of both arrays)
array(B) = array(B) - mean(B) + mean(of both arrays)

Only then I can generate random data and find p-values. Sorry for my question "off-topic" it because of my ignorance in the subject.

Comment: Glad you've resolved this.